# postfix logrotato --> empty maillog_file

Tags: postfix, logrotate

When running `postfix logrotate`, I get the error `fatal: empty 'maillog_file' parameter value. logrotation failed.` There is mention of **logrotate** the main.cf [documentation](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) but I don't understand what needs to be added or if this is where the solution lies.

I also tried adding a postfix file in /etc/logrotate.d/ but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you didn't set the `maillog_file` parameter value in your postfix config, so there is no log file written for postfix (hence no 'rotate' needed/possible.)

You can configure your postfix log file destination by running something like (see more details in [Postfix logging to file or stdout](https://www.postfix.org/MAILLOG_README.html):

```
postfix stop
postconf maillog_file=/var/log/postfix.log
postfix start
```